# How to edit the long equation in the linear format of MS word?

Tags: microsoft-word, display, editing, equations

There's a matrix that has been created in the MS word 2019 illustrated as the following figures. It's found very difficult to edit later, because it becomes so long that exceeds the page width in the linear format. How to edit this equation? Thank you very much.

Figure1

[image]

Figure2

[image]

Figure3

[image]

The text in txt file
[■(c_11&c_12&c_13&c_14&c_15&c_16@c_21&c_22&c_23&c_24&c_25&c_26@c_31&c_32&c_33&c_34&c_35&c_36@c_41&c_42&c_43&c_44&c_45&c_46@c_51&c_52&c_53&c_54&c_55&c_56@c_61&c_62&c_63&c_64&c_65&c_66 )]

Comment: It seems the same problem is in word 2016 as well.

Comment: Why do you want to edit it in linear format instead of professional (which is easier)?

Comment: @Reddy Lutonadio, thank you. It may be because I am used to LaTeX, so use the habit of editing LaTeX to edit the word equation, but at present I have to use the MS word. Another reason is that I feel it is more convenient to edit the source code for writing equation in MS word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break the equation in small parts by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> (see image below, the equation was divided in 3 parts). When you finish editing the parts, go a the beginning of a small parts, press <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to re-attach to the previous part. Repeat the process until you have only one part.

[image]

Comment: I invite you to answer the questions in the link. Thank you. https://superuser.com/questions/1647346/the-set-field-codes-in-ms-word-doesnt-run-correctly